# Reading numbers from file using Scanner

Tags: java

This is my simple program which counts the sum of the numbers in the file

```
int sum = 0;

        try(Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(path)))
        {
            while (s.hasNextInt())
            {
                if (s.hasNextInt())
                {
                    sum += s.nextInt();
                }
                else
                {
                    s.next();
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
```

Why it doesnt work if i do something like that:

Scanner s = new Scanner(path)

instead of

Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(path))

Comment: `Scanner s = new Scanner(path)` Because this class doesn't take a path as string.

Comment: Dupe; [Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException "Graph"](//stackoverflow.com/q/34183189)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop loops only if `s.hasNextInt()` is true (because you wrote `while (s.hasNextInt())`. You then again check: `if (s.hasNextInt()`.

This `if` is useless. Of course `s.hasNextInt()` is true. If it wasn't, the while loop wouldn't have looped!

It sounds like you want to do two things:

1. make that `while (s.hasNext())` instead.
2. Fix your deplorable exception handling. Ditch the catch. Add `throws IOException` to the method (and to `main` if you want, `psv main()` can, and usually should, be declared as `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception`. Less code, and errors with way more detail. Win-win.